# Need Help - Using a Search Bar and DIV Filter (using buttons) at the Same Time

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a website where I'm putting in a bunch of guinea pig foods as div containers on the website - I originally used the filter DIV from w3 and I figured out how to also make a search bar that also will filter them based on the title. The problem I'm running into is that once you use the search bar, the filter buttons stop sorting the way they're supposed to.

Long and short - the filter buttons are unusable with the search bar too. Alternatively I can probably just make the same page and then just have them search on that one if they want to be specific, but I think it can work.

Here's the current website: https://extraordinaryguineapigs.w3spaces.com/new-TEST.html

Here's a Couple of the Cards:

```
<div id="myBtnContainer">


  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('safe')"> Safe</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('treat')"> Treats</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('NR')"> Not Recommended</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('never')"> Never/Toxic</button>
   <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('vitC')">High Vitamin C</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('calcium')"> High Calcium</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('sugar')"> High Sugar</button>
   <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('1')"> 1-2x/Week</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('2')"> 2-3x/Week</button>
   <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('7')"> Every Day</button>

</div>

<div class="container">
  <!----------------Acorn Squash -------------------->
  <div class="filterDiv search vegetables safe 2"><img src="https://specialtyproduce.com/sppics/414.png" class="cropped-ofp">
  <br><font class="title">Acorn Squash</font><br>
 <div class="frequency"> 2-3x per Week</div>

   <div class="amount">  <b>Recommended Amount Per Pig:</b> <br> 1" Cube of Orange Flesh
   <br><font class="amount-notes">No Peel/Seeds/Pulp/Stem </font> </div>
       <div class="title2"><a href="https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/fdc-app.html#/food-details/168472/nutrients" target="_blank">Nutrition Facts per 100g</a></div>
       <div class="nutrition"><table style="width:88%; border: none;">
  <tr>
    <td><b>Vitamin C:</b> 11mg</td>
    <td> <b> Calcium: </b> 33mg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><b>Fats: </b> 0.1g</td>
        <td> <b>Protein:</b> 0.8g</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
     <td><b>Carbs:</b> 10.4g</td>
        <td><b> Sugar:</b> N/A</td>
        </tr>
</table>
    </div>
      <div class="notes">
       <ul id="guts">
      <li>  <b><u>Additional Notes:</b></u> <p style="margin-top:3px;">High carbohydrates and sugar have been linked to obestity, and can cause bloat, digestive upset, or <a href="https://www.mspca.org/angell_services/enterotoxemia-in-pet-rabbits-and-other-herbivores/" target="_blank">enterotoxemia</a>. 
      </p></li></div>
</ul>
  </div>

   <!----------------Alfalfa Sprouts -------------------->
  <div class="filterDiv search vegetables treat 1"><img src="https://images.freshop.com/2311560/54027d67aca0555244556b96acc112e1_large.png" class="cropped-ofp">
  <br><font class="title">Alfalfa Sprouts</font><br>
  <div class="frequency"> 1-2x per Week</div>
   <div class="amount">  <b>Recommended Amount Per Pig:</b> <br> Small Pinch
   <br><font class="amount-notes"> Best for 6m & under or pregnant/nursing sows</font> </div>
    <div class="title2"><a href="https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/fdc-app.html#/food-details/1103333/nutrients" target="_blank">Nutrition Facts per 100g</a></div>
       <div class="nutrition">
<table style="width:88%; border: none;">
  <tr>
    <td><b>Vitamin C:</b> 8.2mg</td>
    <td> <b> Calcium: </b> 32mg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><b>Fats: </b> 0.7g</td>
        <td> <b>Protein:</b> 4g</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
     <td><b>Carbs:</b> 2.1g</td>
        <td><b> Sugar:</b> 0.2g</td>
        </tr>
</table>
    </div>
    </font>
    <div class="notes"> <ul id="urinary">
      <li>  <b><u>Additional Notes:</b></u> <p style="margin-top:3px;">
        High calcium diets have been linked to <a href="https://veterinarypartner.vin.com/default.aspx?pid=19239&catId=102923&id=10817435#:~:text=Diet%3A%20Because%20most%20urinary%20stones,%2C%20dandelion%20greens%2C%20and%20spinach." target="_blank">bladder stones</a> in adults.  </p>
        <p style="margin-top: -8px;"> Excessively high in calcium and protein, should not be fed to pigs with kidney/bladder issues</p></li></ul></div>

</div>
```

Here's the Search Bar:

```
<form id="myForm" class='searchbox' onreset="filterSelection('all')">
    <input class="searchbar" type="text" onkeyup="filter()" placeholder="Search by Food Name.." name="search">
     <input type="button" onclick="myResetFunction()" value="Clear" alt="Clear the search form"></form> <p>
</form> <p>
```

Here's the Javascript

```
<script>
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}

    function filter() {
  let input = document.querySelector('.searchbar').value //<-- Changed to querySelector
  input = input.toLowerCase();
  let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.search'); //<-- Changed to querySelectorAll with '.card' selector.

  //loop over cards and compare search with title.
  cards.forEach((el) => {
    let title = el.querySelector('.title').textContent.toLowerCase();
    el.style.display = title.includes(input) ? "list-item" : "none";
  });
}
function myResetFunction() {
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
 filter();
}

</script>
```

I have done the following so far:

- Since clearing the search bar shows all of it, I tried to attach the filterSelection('all') function to it to see if it was triggering the active button...nope.
- I've tried removing the clear button entirely out of the equation. Once the search bar is touched, it no longer allows function of the buttons.
- I originally had the search bar using filterDiv to find the titles, I added "search" as a class to see if that was the problem... nope.
- I tried making it so when you pushed a button, it would clear the search bar if there was anything there (so there was no conflict)... nope.

I feel like I'm clearly missing some step where I'm re-establishing a function when the searchbar is empty or a button is pushed so everything is reset back to its original state when the website first loads.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I posted all of the code I have. The only other code is the cards and they are just the exact same thing just different text.